# How will be object[] params interpreted if they are passed into another procedure with object[] params?

Tags: c#, parameters

If we have two procedures:

```
public void MyFirstParamsFunction(params object[] items)
{
    //do something
    MySecondParamsFunction(items, "test string", 31415)
}

public void MySecondParamsFunction(params object[] items)
{
    //do something
}
```

How will second procedure interpret the `items` from first? As sole objects, or as one object, that is `object[]`?

Comment: You've written the code. Can't you try it and find out yourself?

Comment: That doesn't seem like it'd be too difficult to create a quick experiment and figure it out for yourself...

Comment: I wish I'd knew about quick-test program for c#, as I haven't learned powershell yet. Also, I have a LINQPad, but I don't know how to use it without some LINQ in test code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`object[] items` will be interpreted as one `object[]` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

This call:

```
MySecondParamsFunction(items, "test string", 31415);
```

Will expand to this:

```
MySecondParamsFunction(new object[] { items, "test string", 31415 });
```

So you'll have 3 items in your `params` array for the call. Your original `items` array will be crammed into the first item in the new array.

If you want to just have a flattened parameter list going into the second method, you can append the new items to the old array using something like this:

```
MySecondParamsFunction(
  items.Concat(new object[] { "test string", 31415 }).ToArray());
```

Or maybe with a nicer extension method:

```
MySecondParamsFunction(items.Append("test string", 31415));

// ...

public static class ArrayExtensions {
  public static T[] Append<T>(this T[] self, params T[] items) {
    return self.Concat(items).ToArray();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you check it yourself you would have noticed that it is seen as a single object.

So in `MySecondParamsFunction` the `items` parameter will have length of 3 in this case.

Answer (score 2):

The params keyword is just a bit of syntactic sugar.

Calling MyFirstParamsFunction(1, 2, 3) is the same as MyFirstParamsFunction(new object[] { 1, 2, 3 }). The compiler injects the code to create the array behind your back.